# JavaScript toggle

Tags: javascript

I made a JavaScript function to hide a link on click of button and its work here the function

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function toggle() 
{
    var ele = document.getElementById("yui-gen1");
    var text = document.getElementById("windows");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
    }
} 
</script>
```

But when it hidea the next link replace its place. I want nothing to replace its place, I want its place after the hiding to be just empty. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Could you include the relevant HTML?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, your problem is that `display:none` causes the affected element to take up no space in the document. What you need is the [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/visibility) property, which hides the affected element but keeps it's space in the document:

```
ele.style.visibility = "hidden";
```

and

```
ele.style.visibility = "visible";
```

should work, instead of [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Display).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting visibility instead. Visibility will still take up the space that the button occupied, it just won't show it. Display removes it altogether so the space will be taken up by the next element.