# Where do I add the visibility toggle in my JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

[I have seen other javascript toggle questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924918/javascript-toggle)

But I am having trouble *adding* this into my method.  I can't wrap my head around where I should drop it in to make it work.

Here is the JavaScript function in question:

```
function injectProductIFrame(w,h){
        var job_id = $("#job_id").val();
        if(job_id != "0")
        {
            var url = "/technician/"+ job_id+"/addProducts";
            $("#iframeContainer").html('<iframe src="'+url+'" width='+w+' height='+h+' />');
        }else{
            alert("Please Select a Job First. Then you can add a product");
        }
    }
```

And here is the view part:

```
</a><a href="#productaddAdd" role="" class="" data-toggle="modal">
                              <button class="btn btn-large" id="product_frame" type="button" onClick='Javascript: injectProductIFrame("90%", "500")'> Product </button>
```

Nothing wrong with this, except I wish for the button to CLOSE the iFrame if the iFrame is showing stuff.  The button right now just functions as "on" and clicking it again changes nothing.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle? wanna check your html.

Comment: I'm not adept using that site (aka I've never used it)

Comment: or you just post your html codes in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this, or something similar, would work

```
    function injectProductIFrame(w,h){
    if($("#iframeContainer").html().length > 0)
    {
       $("#iframeContainer").hide();           
    }
    else
    {
       $("#iframeContainer").show();

       var job_id = $("#job_id").val();
       if(job_id != "0")
       {
           var url = "/technician/"+ job_id+"/addProducts";
           $("#iframeContainer").html('<iframe src="'+url+'" width='+w+' height='+h+' />');
       }else{
           alert("Please Select a Job First. Then you can add a product");
       }   
    }
}
```

Comment: This did work with a few tweaks to make toggle on and off - thanks!